# acess services.py from a model Manager

Tags: django, django-models

I created a `services.py` file on the root directory of an app called **mymoney** and I plan to add helper functions there to keep my `models.py` file with simpler language. Now I wonder, how can I access functions and methods inside the `services.py` from the a model Manager?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date

class Balance(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey('mymoney.account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=2)

    objects = BalanceManager()

    class Meta:
        app_label = "mymoney"
```

**Manager** (a continuation of models.py, that's why no imports)

```
class BalanceManager(models.Manager):
    def balance_inconsistences(balance_dates: dict,
                                initial_date: date,
                                today: date) -> tuple:
        # return tuple with two lists: return of first wrong_balance_dates()
        # and second return of dates_missing_balance_consolidation()
        wrong_dates = wrong_balance_dates(balance_dates, initial_date)
        dates_missing = dates_missing_balance_consolidation(balance_dates,
                                                            initial_date,
                                                            today)
        return wrong_dates, dates_missing
```

**services.py**

```
from mymoney.models import Balance
from datetime import date
from calendar import monthrange


def end_month_dates_since_first_transaction(initial_date: date,
                                            today: date) -> list:
    pass

def wrong_balance_dates(balance_dates: dict, initial_date: date) -> list:
    pass

def dates_missing_balance_consolidation(balance_dates: dict,
                                        initial_date: date,
                                        today: date) -> list:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to mutual import the service and model function. The model file should hold a higher hierarchy than the service file, which means service function should depend on the model, rather than the reverse situation.

There are two ways for you to access the function in Model Manager:

1. Declare the functions inside the model file instead of service file. The service file then can access both model class and those functions as well.
2. Declare the functions in a new file called utils. Since the helper functions in your service function simply use basic structure, it is suitable for you to write helper functions in `util.py` and import utils in `model.py` or `service.py` as you need them.

#### `mymoney/utils/utils.py`

(Or `mymoney/utils.py` depends on your preference)

```
from datetime import date
from calendar import monthrange

def end_month_dates_since_first_transaction(initial_date: date,
                                            today: date) -> list:
    pass

def wrong_balance_dates(balance_dates: dict, initial_date: date) -> list:
    pass

def dates_missing_balance_consolidation(balance_dates: dict,
                                        initial_date: date,
                                        today: date) -> list:
    pass
```

#### `mymoney/models/models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from mymoney.utils import uitls

class BalanceManager(models.Manager):
    def balance_inconsistences(balance_dates: dict,
                                initial_date: date,
                                today: date) -> tuple:
        # return tuple with two lists: return of first wrong_balance_dates()
        # and second return of dates_missing_balance_consolidation()
        wrong_dates = utils.wrong_balance_dates(balance_dates, initial_date)
        dates_missing = utils.dates_missing_balance_consolidation(balance_dates,
                                                            initial_date,
                                                            today)
        return wrong_dates, dates_missing


class Balance(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey('mymoney.account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15,decimal_places=2)

    objects = BalanceManager()

    class Meta:
        app_label = "mymoney"
```

#### `mymoney/services/services.py`

```py
from mymoney.models import Balance

# Do stuff with model class...
```

My simple style of code behind model-service relation:

- `util` should be the simple function without involving and customized content, you should only use packages that is not from these django app. For instance, in your case, the functions are just some date-related data manipulator.`utils` can be used anywhere in your own django file because its independence.
- model: define the model class.
- service: a mediator between view and model, import the service in the view, and the service should expose proper function to the view, so you can have a clear and intuitive code process in the view function.

for example, instead of get instance in view like this:

```py
def update_project_view(req, project_id):
    # fetch project
    project.title = req.input.get('title')
    project.owner = req.input.get('owner')
    project.member_count = req.input.get('member_count')
    # ......
    project.save()
```

You can pack these process into project_service, with a update_project function:

```py
# project_services.py
def update_project(input_dict)
    project.title = input_dict.get('title')
    project.owner = input_dict.get('owner')
    project.member_count = input_dict.get('member_count')
    # ......
    project.save()
    return project


# project_view.py
from project_services import update_project
def update_project_view(req, project_id):
    updated_project = update_project(req.input)
```

---

I'm not a native speaker, sorry for my poor choice of words, hope these note can help you some way.

Comment: can you please include code on how you would reorganize the import calls with the util.py file? I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Pabluez update in the original Answer post.